# C# Sockets, receive big files

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm working with asyn sockets now. I have a callback function 'onDataReceived', which is triggered whenever I receive any data.

First I was getting a single char at a time, so I changed socketPacket data buffer to a big array. Now when ever I receive data, I get it all at once, but when I try to send a bigger file, it doesn't work once it exceeds the array size.

My question is this. I have a multithreaded socket server. How can I determinate whenever all data is received? for example I need to send an image, I encode the image into base64 and contruct a command "BASE64IMAGE" and then server reads the string until it reaches END_OF_DATA? is there a better way to do it? thanks!

Comment: You can use HTTP Protocol to send files , so that u can use the http headers to represent details about data being sent ..Also http based socket classes are available as libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is this. I have a multithreaded socket server. How can I determinate whenever all data is received?

There are three standard options for sending a "message" (whether that's an image or whatever - a whole blob of data which may be large):

- One message per connection: you can detect the end of the message by the other end closing the connection
- Some sort of "end-message" marker: as you read the data, you check for a special marker which indicates the end of the message. If the marker could occur naturally, you'll need to escape it - and unescape as you read
- A header indicating the size of the message before the actual data is sent - just read that many bytes

Personally, I like the last option - it makes reading the data and being sure that you've got it all much simpler than the first two options. You can allocate the right amount of memory to receive the data before you start, etc. However, it doesn't cope well when you don't know the message size before you start. You can modify the scheme by having multiple "chunks" for a single message, where you send the chunk size then the data, and a chunk size of 0 indicates the end of the data.

Note that if you're transferring data over just a socket, and you *don't* need it to be 7-bit clean ASCII, I *wouldn't* convert to Base-64 first. Just transfer it as binary data - your code will be simpler and more efficient both in time and bandwidth.

Comment: A complete file can have been sent over a connection that is not closed gracefully (and therefore be treated as an incomplete file)

Comment: @jgauffin: I believe TCP will indicate the difference between those two though, and client libraries (in say Java or .NET) will throw an exception accordingly. That's my understanding, anyway.

Comment: Just design your application level protocol. For example, send *file information header* which contains file size and then the file content. If the server does not receive a file completely (client disconnected, for example), the server treats the file as "incompleted".

Comment: @JonSkeet: true, but my experience is that developers treat exceptions as exceptions and not as something that went ok but was not properly closed. I'm just saying that the solution is possible but nothing that should be recommended. The third options is the most robust way just as you say.

Comment: @jgauffin: If I were using the first approach, you'd *have* to treat it that way. I prefer the third approach too, but it's worth knowing about the first (and that you *can* trust a "no more data" response to a read) due to existing protocols, e.g. HTTP 1.0 with no content length.

Answer (score 1):

You can first send the number of bytes you are about to send. The receiving side reads this first, then knows to expect that many bytes in the future.

For example, you encode your file and determine that the encoded size is 800 bytes. You send the number 800 (in, say, four bytes), then the file.

The receiving side reads four bytes, gets the number 800, then knows to read 800 more bytes to receive the entire file.

This is known as length prefixing.